# I need a function that maps an object inside my object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, object, mapping

I've been trying many ways to map the products inside a menu object whom are also inside a restaurants array, but i can't find the exact way to map it. I'm already maping the image, location, name and reviews but when i try to map the menu, it brings me an (object, object) in my console or just the element without maping it.
How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
    const fillRestaurants = (restaurante) => {
    const {name, ubicacion, image, calificacion, menu} = restaurante;
    rName.innerText = name;
    rAddress.innerText = ubicacion;
    rReview.innerText = calificacion;
    rImage.setAttribute("src", image);
    rMenu.setAttribute('src', menu)
  }
```

And this is how my db.json looks:

````
        {
          "refresco": [
            {
              "coca-cola": "https://res.cloudinary.com/walmart-labs/image/upload/w_960,dpr_auto,f_auto,q_auto:best/gr/images/product-images/img_large/00000007500761L.jpg",
              "sprite": "https://res.cloudinary.com/walmart-labs/image/upload/w_960,dpr_auto,f_auto,q_auto:best/gr/images/product-images/img_large/00750105536631L.jpg",
              "fanta": "https://res.cloudinary.com/walmart-labs/image/upload/w_960,dpr_auto,f_auto,q_auto:best/gr/images/product-images/img_large/00750105530377L.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "image": "https://imagenes.elpais.com/resizer/hAha099uGI7HWlJh9iunniCJ07Q=/1960x1470/cloudfront-eu-central-1.images.arcpublishing.com/prisa/2MRLAMWNLJE3TBYELF4EGKKREQ.jpg",
      "note": "Una tienda de abarrotes dedicada a la excelencia",
      "calificacion": 5
    },```
````

Comment: i don't see menu object in json but if you're getting [object, object] you better `JSON.stringify(menu)`

Comment: Thank you. Now it shows the first element of my array, but how can i map all of them inside my menu?

Comment: menu is an array I think so you should loop it first and then display / map it.